# How to equal the variables in xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML of the following process.

```
<document>
 <map>
  <sec>
   <title>Title 1</title>
   <ref idref="R1"/>
   ...
  </sec>
  <sec>
   <title>Title 1</title>
   <ref idref="R11"/>
   ...
  </sec>
 </map>
</document>

<document>
 <ref id="R1"><p>Paragraph one</p></ref>
</document>
...
<document>
 <ref id="R11"><p>Paragraph eleven</p></ref>
</document>
...
```

The output should be follow below.

```
<div>
 <title>Title 1</title>
 <p>Paragraph one</p>
</div>
...
<div>
 <title>Title 2</title>
 <p>Paragraph eleven</p>
</div>
```

We have to refer the id to which title. So how to equal the variables in xsl.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key

Comment: Is your input a single XML file, or multiple XML documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `xsl:key` to lookup the `ref` elements by their `id` attribute

```
<xsl:key name="ref" match="document/ref[@id]" use="@id" />
```

So, for example, if you were positioned on a `ref` element with an `idref`, you could do something like this

```
<xsl:template match="ref">
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('ref', @idref)/*" />
</xsl:template>
```

For example, try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="ref" match="document/ref[@id]" use="@id" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document/map/sec" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ref">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('ref', @idref)/*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sec">
        <div>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When you apply it on well-formed XML, like this...

```
<documents>
<document>
 <map>
  <sec>
   <title>Title 1</title>
   <ref idref="R1"/>
  </sec>
  <sec>
   <title>Title 1</title>
   <ref idref="R11"/>
  </sec>
 </map>
</document>
<document>
 <ref id="R1"><p>Paragraph one</p></ref>
</document>
<document>
 <ref id="R11"><p>Paragraph eleven</p></ref>
</document>
</documents>
```

The following is output

```
<div>
   <title>Title 1</title>
   <p>Paragraph one</p>
</div>
<div>
   <title>Title 1</title>
   <p>Paragraph eleven</p>
</div>
```

See it in action at http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYiS